# How to set optional properties on Google Dataproc Cluster using Java API?

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to create Dataproc cluster using Java API following this documentation
https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-lib

Sample code is as below

```
  public static void createCluster() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO(developer): Replace these variables before running the sample.
    String projectId = "your-project-id";
    String region = "your-project-region";
    String clusterName = "your-cluster-name";
    createCluster(projectId, region, clusterName);
  }

  public static void createCluster(String projectId, String region, String clusterName)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String myEndpoint = String.format("%s-dataproc.googleapis.com:443", region);

    // Configure the settings for the cluster controller client.
    ClusterControllerSettings clusterControllerSettings =
        ClusterControllerSettings.newBuilder().setEndpoint(myEndpoint).build();

    // Create a cluster controller client with the configured settings. The client only needs to be
    // created once and can be reused for multiple requests. Using a try-with-resources
    // closes the client, but this can also be done manually with the .close() method.
    try (ClusterControllerClient clusterControllerClient =
        ClusterControllerClient.create(clusterControllerSettings)) {
      // Configure the settings for our cluster.
      InstanceGroupConfig masterConfig =
          InstanceGroupConfig.newBuilder()
              .setMachineTypeUri("n1-standard-1")
              .setNumInstances(1)
              .build();
      InstanceGroupConfig workerConfig =
          InstanceGroupConfig.newBuilder()
              .setMachineTypeUri("n1-standard-1")
              .setNumInstances(2)
              .build();
      ClusterConfig clusterConfig =
          ClusterConfig.newBuilder()
              .setMasterConfig(masterConfig)
              .setWorkerConfig(workerConfig)
              .build();
      // Create the cluster object with the desired cluster config.
      Cluster cluster =
          Cluster.newBuilder().setClusterName(clusterName).setConfig(clusterConfig).build();

      // Create the Cloud Dataproc cluster.
      OperationFuture<Cluster, ClusterOperationMetadata> createClusterAsyncRequest =
          clusterControllerClient.createClusterAsync(projectId, region, cluster);
      Cluster response = createClusterAsyncRequest.get();

      // Print out a success message.
      System.out.printf("Cluster created successfully: %s", response.getClusterName());

    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
      System.err.println(String.format("Error executing createCluster: %s ", e.getMessage()));
    }
  }
}
```

So based on the documentation i am able to create it successfully but there are few optional properties which i am not able to figure out how to set it here, for reference below screenshot of it which can be done using the Google Cloud console.

[image]

These properties can be added using Google Cloud SDK as below

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create my-cluster \
    --region=region \
    --properties=spark:spark.executor.memory=4g \
    ... other args ...
```

How to set this using Java API. Also the exact same thing for Labels as well, how can we set the labels on the cluster using Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check complete [API reference](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-dataproc/latest/index.html) for Dataproc Java client library.

Specifically, to set properties you want to look at [SoftwareConfig.Builder](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-dataproc/latest/com/google/cloud/dataproc/v1beta2/SoftwareConfig.Builder.html#putAllProperties-java.util.Map-). Similarly you can associate a label to a Cluster with [Cluster.Builder](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-dataproc/latest/com/google/cloud/dataproc/v1beta2/Cluster.Builder.html#putAllLabels-java.util.Map-).

Comment: Thanks Henry.. It worked, regarding the SoftwareConfig i did come across this but as the name says SoftwareConfig was a bit skeptical. Also regarding the Labels i was setting it through the Cluster builder but always kept getting an error "Invalid argument" with no other hints as to what is going wrong in the exception messages. On closely reading the documents I got to know that the labels key and value both can only have lowercase letters whereas i was giving an upper case letter in the key. The error being thrown by the Google Java API was not at all clear.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Me personally has't directly used Dataproc Java API, some of this information you can also get from Dataproc public Documentation as well, e.g. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/creating-managing-labels#requirements.