# Adding Labels to DataProc Cluster using Java Code

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am new to GCP and currently i am looking to create a Dataproc Cluster using Java and add certain labels to it.

For cluster creation, i am using the following code:

```
    String clusterName = "XXXXXX";
    String projectId   = "YYYYYY";
    String region      = "us-central1";

    String myEndpoint = String.format("%s-dataproc.googleapis.com:443", region);


    ClusterControllerSettings clusterControllerSettings = ClusterControllerSettings.newBuilder()
            .setEndpoint(myEndpoint).build();

    ClusterControllerClient clusterControllerClient = ClusterControllerClient
            .create(clusterControllerSettings);

        InstanceGroupConfig masterConfig = InstanceGroupConfig.newBuilder().setMachineTypeUri("n1-standard-1")
                .setNumInstances(1).build();
        InstanceGroupConfig workerConfig = InstanceGroupConfig.newBuilder().setMachineTypeUri("n1-standard-1")
                .setNumInstances(2).build();
        ClusterConfig clusterConfig = ClusterConfig.newBuilder()
                .setMasterConfig(masterConfig).setWorkerConfig(workerConfig).build();
        

        Cluster cluster = Cluster.newBuilder().setClusterName(clusterName).setConfig(clusterConfig).build();


        OperationFuture<Cluster, ClusterOperationMetadata> createClusterAsyncRequest = clusterControllerClient
                .createClusterAsync(projectId, region, cluster);
        Cluster response = createClusterAsyncRequest.get();
```

Cluster creation is working fine.
But i am not able to add labels to the cluster during creation using java code.
Any suggestions?

Labels from GCP Console looks like this:[labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4n7sV.jpg)

Comment: Please ask the [Developers](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-common/blob/master/troubleshooting/readme.md#ask-the-developers) to introduce add label options in [java-dataproc](https://github.com/googleapis/java-dataproc/blob/master/samples/snippets/src/main/java/CreateCluster.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java API already supports that. I believe you can add label to the cluster as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886310/how-to-set-optional-properties-on-google-dataproc-cluster-using-java-api/62888413#62888413)